# Scala: How to extend a third party class with custom attributes

Tags: scala

I need to extend an external class with an attribute... and since `dynamic` could not be applied in that case, I've no other option than create a wrapper like this:

```
class MyWrapper(val otherClass: OtherClass, val myAttribute: Int) {

  ...
}

val myWrapper = new MyWrapper(new OtherClass, 1)
```

Then, I invoke `OtherClass` members like this:

```
myWrapper.otherClass.foo
```

Is there any trick to have a call like this?

```
myWrapper.foo
```

I've tried with `apply`... but it doesn't work:

```
class MyWrapper(val otherClass: OtherClass, val myAttribute: Int) {

  def apply = otherClass
}
```

Furthermore I cannot extend `OtherClass` like this...

```
class MyWrapper(val myAttribute: Int) extends OtherClass {

  ...
}
```

... since I need to use a factory class that deserializes it from a byte array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Pimp My Library](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766) pattern (I believe they are trying to downplay the name though). Basically, you can use implicits to accomplish this. In fact, you can use an [`implicit class`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html) as of 2.10

```
object Pimper{
  implicit class WrapperClass(wrapped: OtherClass){
    def additionalStuff....
  }
}

import Pimper._
new OtherClass().additionalStuff
```

There is already a lot on implicits, so I will let you research the rest on your own :)